# single radiobutton selection in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

I have a gridview in which each row (only 1 column) has 1 radiobutton, 2 dropdowns and 1 radiobuttonlist.

As initialy i faced the problems to restrict the radiobutton seletion to one. But later i acheived by using below code.

```
selectedRadio = (RadioButton)sender.Text;
foreach (DataListItem dlItem in datalist.Items)
        {
            GridView grid = (GridView)dlItem.FindControl("gvList");
            if (grid != null)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grid.Rows)
                {
                    RadioButton rdo = gridRow.FindControl("radio") as RadioButton;

                    string radioname = rdo.Text;

                    if (selectedRadio == radioname)
                    {
                        if (dummyarray.Contains(selectedRadio))
                        {
                           dummyarray.Remove(radioname);
                            rdo.Checked = false;
                        }
```

/* Check New selection  */

```
                        else
                        {
                            if (!dummyarray.Contains(selectedRadio))
                            {
                                dummyarray.Add(radioname);
                            }
                            rdo.Checked = true;
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rdo.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As the previous selected value stored in dummyarray(it has ViewState Property), it will uncheck that radiobutton and will check new ones.

Now the issues is after new radiobutton is checked. and on selecting its associate dropdown , a postback occurs and as current values stores in dummy array. its unselecting again.

Again i am failing in my requirement.

Comment: Not sure if i have understood correct , Do you want to disable a postback  on your dropdown ?

Comment: No we cant remove postback. because on postback of every control... we have to check weater all controls in that row is selected... then only we have to enter those details in main LIST<T>. So without removing postback.... i need to this thing to be acheived. seleting single radiobutton in gridview

Comment: make a method that collect all the checked value and rebinds your data. Call that method on page post back.